# Cómo sumar elementos de una columna incluida en una cosulta JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT()) en MySql

Tags: php, mysql, json, jsonobject

Estimada comunidad, necesito generar una consulta a una tabla , donde el resultado sea la suma de las mediciones del mismo mes en el mismo año. Como necesito que la respuesta sea graficada, lo más lógico es hacer una consulta del tipo JSON_ARRAYAGG con el fin de obtener los valores en un json.

**La tabla es algo como esto (ejemplo simplificado)**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**La consulta que tengo hasta ahora, es la siguiente:**

```
SELECT YEAR(hora_medicion) AS anio,JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT( 'mes', MONTH(hora_medicion), 'metros', fondo_medido))AS datos  FROM grafico GROUP BY anio
```

Y la respuesta que obtengo es **casi** lo que necesito:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es "casi lo que necesito", porque el mes 1 del 2021 tiene dos mediciones y se deberían sumar quedando algo como esto:

2021  [{"mes": 1, **"metros": "300"**},  {"mes": 2 "metros": "300"},...

2022  [{"mes": 1, "metros": "600"}, {"mes": 2, "metros": "800"},...

No me ha sido posible incluir un sum(metros) dentro del JSON_ARRAYAGG por que mysql no entendería cuando sumar y todos los intentos que he realizado han sido infructuosos. He intentado parametrizando "metros" y haciendo el select sum(metros) afuera del JSON_ARRAYAGG pero tampoco he podido. Obviamente estoy haciendo algo mal.

Agradezco de antemano vuestra ayuda.

Saludos!

Comment: Existen varias posibilidades, aquí muestro un par de ellas dbfiddle. La primera posibilidad usa una sub-consulta y la segunda posibilidad usa una Expresión de Tabla Común (CTE). Espero le sea útil.

Comment: @wchiquito, Gracias por tu comentario, si gustas respondes a la pregunta para poder ver el link entender más lo que mencionas.

Comment: Disculpe, efectivamente no incluí el enlace al [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7bed9a2e28605d030f0e9708758f06b4) mencionado.

Comment: @wchiquito, excelente respuesta, por favor publícala para darte el ok y  le sirva a otros usuarios